# How to read with java a callback from a kotlin class (Android)

Tags: java, android, kotlin, callback

This is my kotlin class:

```
class example {

    var a = 0

    fun add(b: Int, callback: (Int) -> Unit){
        a += b
        callback(a)
    }
}
```

How do I use this function in a java code?

Comment: You initialize the class and then you can access inner methods.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Edit:**
As @Drawn Raccoon mentioned in the comments, you can call the `add` method from java code simply by returning Unit.INSTANCE:

Java:

```
example e = new example();
e.add(16, a -> {
    // do some work with 'a'
    return Unit.INSTANCE;
});
```

Or call it from kotlin without returning any value:

Kotlin:

```
add(16) {
    a -> // do some work with 'a'
}
```

**Not correct(for correct answer refer to Edit section):**

I think you can't use `Unit` type for output type of callback that will be called from java code. `Unit` is not recognized in Java.
Instead you can use `Void?` (I don't know about 'Void' and now I can't test it).

Code in kotlin:

```
class example {

    var a = 0

    fun add(b: Int, callback: (Int) -> Void?){
        a += b
        callback(a)
    }
}
```

And calling it from java:

```
example e = new example();
e.add(16, a -> {
    // do some work with 'a'
    return null;
})
```

And call from kotlin:

```
val example = example()
e.add(16, { a ->
    // do some work with 'a'
    null
})
```

[ In addition, the 'example' is not a good name for kotlin or java classes and try to use upper case, like 'Example' ]

Comment: "I think you can't use Unit" - it's not true, "Unit is not recognized in Java" - and it's not true. Unit is recognized in Java as Void/void automatically

Comment: @DrawnRaccoon You are right. Unit is recognized in Java. But as far as I know we can not return a Unit value from java. Can we? [If we could return a Unit value from java then we could call the callback given in the question]

Comment: do the same as with Void, return null;

Comment: also we can return Unit.INSTANCE;